# Escaping variable group values when passing using in Azure CLI task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using a variable group to store some secrets, that I want to deploy into a key vault as part of my pipeline.

I do this by passing the values as secret parameters to a bicep file via the Azure CLI.

My pipeline step looks like this:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: deploy bicep template
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azure_subscription }}
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: | 
      az deployment group create `
        --name foo.$(Build.BuildNumber) `
        --resource-group my-rg-name `
        --template-file $(Pipeline.Workspace)/iac/main.bicep `
        --parameters environment='${{ parameters.environment }}' `
            kv_secret_one='$(bd_kv_secret_one)' `
            kv_secret_two='$(bd_kv_secret_two)'
```

Now, the issue is that these secrets could contain all sorts of special characters that break my script. So I found some suggestions that I could use double quotes inside the single quotes like this `kv_secret_two='"$(bd_kv_secret_two)"'`

However, if the value of the secret contains a " then the script breaks.

This leads me to think there must be a better way of doing this, but I cannot find it.

What is the correct way to pass `--parameters` so that they are escaped properly, no matter what characters the may contain?

Comment: hi mortenbock, what is the latest status of your issue? have the answers of vince's and mine helped?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a bicep parameter file.

First, construct a [parameter file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameter-files) including all your parameter values, escaped as necessary. You could do this in a script task for example.

Secondly, name that file when doing the deployment instead of listing individual parameters:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: deploy bicep template
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azure_subscription }}
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: | 
      az deployment group create `
        --name foo.$(Build.BuildNumber) `
        --resource-group my-rg-name `
        --template-file $(Pipeline.Workspace)/iac/main.bicep `
        --parameters @main.parameters.json
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not quite sure how to construct that file on the fly, from my variable group, and ensure that the values in the file are then correctly escaped.

Doesn't this just move the escaping challenge to the previous task?

Comment: It moves it to a different task, but scripting out a file (e.g. using powershell) can guarantee that *any* significant character can be escaped. If your data might include either single-quotes or double-quotes, it is very difficult to escape in the az cli call.

Comment: I might need to create a second question for this, but how would I pass the variable to a powershell script, that can save it to a file, without having to worry about escaping the value? 

I'm missing the part where my variable becomes "a reference to a string" and not "a string injected into a script" I guess.

Comment: Ah, I confess I hadn't thought of that :(

Answer (score -1):

You could check this document for [double quotation in parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?tabs=bash%2Cbash2#use-quotation-marks-in-parameters), and edit your value to escape with the equivalent of the string `"{\"key\": \"value\"}"`